# How can the modification date of a file be in the future?

Tags: linux, timestamp

Whenever I change a file on my (Scientific Linux 6, 64bit) machine, its modification date is set in the future:

```
bash$ touch new.txt && stat -c %y new.txt && date
2016-09-19 12:33:08.763882267 +0200
Mo 19. Sep 12:30:21 CEST 2016
```

How can this possibly happen and how can I make the modification dates sane again? It *seems* as if the difference between the actual time and the modification time is increasing the longer the machine is active.

Comment: Are the files stored on a network share?  If so you're seeing the difference in clock sync between the client and server.

Comment: You are right. The mount is of a network share. Testing on a local mount, the time stamps agree with one another; so the other machine's clock is not synced up. I didn't think of this ... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As confirmed in comments above, **you are working with a networked filesystem** where the server and client times are not synced.  The file is created with a timestamp provided by the server and so it is **3 minutes in the future** from the perspective of your workstation.  This is easily avoidable if you're running NTP or some other time synchronization system.